# Get Company Name and Title with Community Management API

Tags: linkedin-api

was wondering if there's an alternative to get user's company and title with just a basicprofile permission from the Community Management API?

Appreciate any advices, please correct me if I'm wrong, thank you.

I am still waiting for the app to be set up as it requires some approvals. Meanwhile, what I can find through Learn is just the fields from the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile